# Initial directory for OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

The file dialog has to open the last directory location that was used before it was shut down, but I have no idea how to do this. My colleague only shows me the example of word, when you click "file" it shows the last used files, he told me to use a register or an INI file, which I have never used before.

Here is the code I am using:

```
string f_sOudeLocatie = @"D:\path\is\classified";

private void btBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    fdlg.Title = "Zoek de CSV file";
    fdlg.InitialDirectory = f_sOudeLocatie;
    fdlg.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    fdlg.FilterIndex = 1;
    fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
    if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        tbGekozenBestand.Text = fdlg.FileName;
        tbVeranderNaamIn.Text = Path.GetDirectoryName(fdlg.FileName);
        f_sOudeLocatie = Path.GetDirectoryName(fdlg.FileName);
        f_sSourceFileName = fdlg.FileName;
        f_sDestFileName = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(fdlg.FileName)) + ".csv";
        btOpslaan.Enabled = true;
        tbVeranderNaamIn.ReadOnly = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try run your application a couple of times. It should be native behaviour that Windows explorer windows open is the last directory where there was opened some file. I works for me.

Comment: I think this should work because `InitialDirectory` is set to `f_sOutdeLocatie` which is saved everytime user clicks `OK`.

Comment: What isn't working? Have you asked your colleague?

Comment: Title wouldn't be *how to store a value and retrieve it?* No really related to `OpenFileDialog` I think...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you'll create the `OpenFileDialog` outside the button click event it should remember the last folder you've been

```
string f_sOudeLocatie = @"D:\path\is\classified";
OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    fdlg.Title = "Zoek de CSV file";
    fdlg.InitialDirectory = f_sOudeLocatie;
    fdlg.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    fdlg.FilterIndex = 1;
    fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
}
private void btBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        fdlg.InitialDirectory = fdlg.FileName.Remove(fdlg.FileName.LastIndexOf("\\"));// THIS LINE IS IMPORTENT

        tbGekozenBestand.Text = fdlg.FileName;
        tbVeranderNaamIn.Text = Path.GetDirectoryName(fdlg.FileName);
        f_sOudeLocatie = Path.GetDirectoryName(fdlg.FileName);
        f_sSourceFileName = fdlg.FileName;
        f_sDestFileName = Path.GetFileName( Path.GetDirectoryName(fdlg.FileName) ) + ".csv";
        btOpslaan.Enabled = true;
        tbVeranderNaamIn.ReadOnly = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you may use `Path` static methods: `Path.GetDirectoryName(fdlg.FileName)` instead of recode it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set

```
fdlg.RestoreDirectory = false;
```

**Reason:**

> RestoreDirectory property makes sure that the value in
>   Environment.CurrentDirectory will be reset before the OpenFileDialog
>   closes.  **If RestoreDirectory is set to false**, then
>   Environment.CurrentDirectory will be set to whatever directory the
>   OpenFileDialog was last open to. As explained [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c43ddefb-1274-4ceb-9cda-c78d860b687c/how-to-get-the-last-directory-after-open-filedialog)

Comment: Actually this is not true, Environment.CurrentDirectory is not changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use registry to store the last directory location. And each time you open the file dialogue, get the value from the registry and set as the default location. When it closed store the location back to registry.

This code project article explains you well about reading and writing to registry
[ReadWriteDeleteFromRegistry](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C)

If you choose to use INI file, some search will give you examples of how to read and write from INI file